# How can I use Mojolicious rendering in a standalone Perl script?

Tags: perl, templating, mojolicious

I want to render `.html.ep` templates using Mojolicious rendering engine in a standalone script which sends e-mails and is run from cron:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use feature ':5.10';

use Mojo::Base -strict;
use Mojolicious::Renderer;
use Data::Dumper;


my $renderer = Mojolicious::Renderer->new();
push @{$renderer->paths}, '/app/templates';

my $template = $renderer->get_data_template({
    template => 'template_name',
    format => 'html',
    handler => 'ep'
});

print Dumper($template) . "\n";
```

However, `$template` is always undefined.

The template file is `/app/templates/template_name.html.ep`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `get_data_template` is for `__DATA__` sections, not files.

Comment: Ok, managed to make it work with a __DATA__ section, but can I do the same with files?

Comment: I've found it. See my update.

Comment: Yes, this is it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using [`get_data_template`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Renderer#get_data_template) from Mojo::Renderer, which is used for loading templates from the `__DATA__` section of your current source code file.

**In fact, Mojo::Renderer is the wrong thing to use**. You want [Mojo::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Template), the stand-alone template engine as a module.

```
use Mojo::Template;

my $mt = Mojo::Template->new( vars => 1 );
my $email_body = $mt->render_file( 'test.html.ep', { one => 1, two => 2 } );
say $email_body;
```

With *test.html.ep*:

```
The magic numbers are <%= $one %> and <%= $two %>.
```

Output:

```
The magic numbers are 1 and 2.
```

The [option `vars`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Template#vars) is important so it accepts named variables instead of an argument list.

Comment: I've tried to use render_to_string, but it doesn't work in a standalone script

Comment: Going to put the whole e-mail template to the DATA section

Comment: @Victor it needs a `$c` as well I think. You should read the source of the Renderer. You need a handler, and then you can do some part of what `_render_template` does yourself. Maybe if the template gets loaded properly it will just work.

Comment: @Victor that would be the easy way out I guess, but maintenance hell :(

Comment: Found out that get_data_template does not render anything, it just does what it's name says: returns the DATA section content

Comment: @Victor that's what I said in my first sentence ;)